# How to modify signed build apk name in Android studio in 2019

Tags: apk, signed

I have created a signed apk build from Android Studio and by default it's name is app-release.apk .
I just want to rename it to my app name. What should I do, please suggest?

Answer (score 0):

**Here are the steps to modify generated apk name :**

Open app level **"build.gradle"** file and apply below code

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            debuggable false
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

            applicationVariants.all { variant ->
                variant.outputs.all {
                    def applicationName="customized_apk_name"
//                    outputFileName = "${applicationName}_${variant.buildType.name}_${defaultConfig.versionName}.apk"
                    outputFileName = "${applicationName}.apk"
                }
            }

        }
}
```